# Selenium 3.0.1 with new FirefoxDriver + Marionette stuck on start page

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm migrating my Selenium app from 2.53 to 3.0.1. First of all, I want to test it in a small app just launching a browser and navigating to a specific page.
Moreover, I want to use a custom binary for Firefox (version 51.0, Portable App).

This is my **code**:

```
public class Selenium {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            WebDriver driver = createFFDriver();
            driver.navigate().to("http:....");
            System.out.println("Finished");
        }

        public static WebDriver createFFDriver(){
            System.setProperty(GeckoDriverService.GECKO_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY,"foo/geckodriver64.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setCapability("firefox_binary","foo/firefox.exe");
            return new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
        }
}
```

The browser actually opens up, but blocked.
**Logs**:

```
1486713046153   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:12466 
Feb 10, 2017 8:50:46 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
createSession INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1486713046731   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path foo\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.p25D0Gb1sBQm
1486713046752   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser foo\firefox\51.0\FirefoxPortable.exe
1486713046782   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:52818
```

Why is Geckodriver listening on `127.0.0.1:12466` but it's trying to connect to Marionette on `localhost:52818` ?

This is the page where I get stuck:
[image]

EDIT:
It gets stuck in the RemoteWebDriver startSession method:

```
Response response = this.execute("newSession", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Portable Edition of Firefox isn't working well with Gecko Driver.
It works as expected with traditional Firefox (51.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code with Selenium V 3.0.1 and Firefox 51.0.1 (32-bit) and was successful in accessing URL/other web driver functions/no blocking.

**UPDATE**

`WebDriver firefox;
                                                                                           System.setProperty(GeckoDriverService.GECKO_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY,"pathtogeckodriver");
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            firefox = new FirefoxDriver(  new FirefoxBinary(
                            new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
                            "\\FirefoxPortable\\FirefoxPortable.exe")), profile);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");`

This works perfectly with Portable Firefox version (51.0.1)

Comment: It doesn't work. Do you use the Portable App version of Firefox ?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work neither... Still stuck at user profile page when the browser starts up. Have you got an idea about what config point may distinguish between us ?

Comment: What exception do you get? / where did you get stuck?

Comment: I got no exception, it's stuck in WebDriver instanciation. I added a screenshot of the page where I get stuck

Comment: could not try more, It may be compatibility issues with Selenium and Portable Firefox versions

Comment: Actually you're right. It works well for a basic FF 51.0.1 distro but with Portable it's stuck. Thanks pointing me to this direction !